# Page does not contain a definition for Frame - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been working on this error for 5 days now and I still haven't found a solution.

So I have a WPF Page called *'MainSCR'* that has a Frame named *'frame'* in it, and **I Want to make a method that returns the Frame so I can use it anywhere.** However, I have gotten an error saying `'MainSCR' does not contain a definition for 'frame'`.

```cs
class GlobalData{
  public Frame GetFrame()
  {
    //currently the line under this comment doesn't work, what can I replace it with?
    return MainSCR.frame;
  }
}
```

I hope I've explained my problem well, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the `MainSCR` as the input parameter to the new form and from there you can have full access to the `MainSCR` controls. Follow the example below

```
public class MainSCR : Window
{
    public MainSCR()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void GetWindow2()
    {
       Window2 wnd = new Window2(this);
       wnd.Show();
   }
}

public class Window2 : Window
{
   MainSCR mainSCR;
   public Window2(MainSCR _mainSCR)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      mainSCR = _mainSCR;
   }
   public Frame GetFrame()
   {
      return mainSCR.frame;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just had to remove the ```mainSCR = _mainSCR;``` and the parameter in the ```public Window2(MainSCR _mainSCR)```